# Why is this simple bash script destroying my computer?

Tags: shell-script, cp, kernel-panic

Something weird is happening with a seemingly inoffensive script I have. I need to copy a series of files to some locations in the system and I have the following script to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get all the files from the file
LINES=$(cat Release-Nodejs/dependencies.txt)

# Copy each file to its location as indicated in the file
for LINE in ${LINES}
do
    LIBRARY=$(basename ${LINE})
    LIBRARY=Release-Nodejs/${LIBRARY}
    LIB_PATH=$(dirname ${LINE})
    echo -e "Copying \e[38;5;10m${LIBRARY}\e[0m to \e[38;5;11m${LIB_PATH}\e[0m"
    cp ${LIBRARY} ${LIB_PATH}
done
```

The script is getting the files and locations from the `dependencies.txt` file whose contents are:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlienc.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcares.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67
```

If I comment out the `cp ${LIBRARY} ${LIB_PATH}` line I get:

[image: Script output]

So I know I'm getting the filenames and paths correctly. It is when I uncomment the `cp ${LIBRARY} ${LIB_PATH}` line and run the script with `sudo` that the script destroys my system *(by the way, this is harmless because I'm testing this on a VM)*. When doing this the screen just goes black and I have to force close the VM window. Then when I try to run the VM again I get this:

[image: Dead System]

And I have to completely reinstall UBUNTU.

I wonder why this is happening since I can manually execute the `cp` on the command line for each file and nothing bad happens, the files just get copied to their destinations.

---

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in one of the comments and in the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), the problem I'm trying to solve is that I'm creating a native nodejs module on my machine which has `node v12.18.1` and that shall be used on a machine with `node v 10.19.0` and I absolutely can't update the node version on the target machine or install other packages that include the dependencies.

When I execute `ldd mymodule.node` I get:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe878c6000)
libnode.so.72 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72 (0x00007f9bd34fb000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9bd34e0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9bd34be000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9bd32d4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9bd5b1e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9bd32b7000)
libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f9bd32a9000)
libbrotlienc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlienc.so.1 (0x00007f9bd3215000)
libcares.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcares.so.2 (0x00007f9bd31fe000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f9bd31d2000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f9bd2ef5000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f9bd2e61000)
libicui18n.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67 (0x00007f9bd2b4f000)
libicuuc.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67 (0x00007f9bd2961000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9bd295b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9bd277a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9bd262b000)
libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f9bd2608000)
libicudata.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67 (0x00007f9bd0aed000)
```

And that is why I'm trying to do what I'm trying to do in this question. So the real question here is; **How can I include these dependencies along with the `.node` module so I can deploy this without having to update anything on the target?**

I would prefer to link all these into the module and have only one .node file that includes everything and doesn't depend on system libraries, but I don't think that is possible, or is it?

Comment: You are over-writing the shared libraries and setting their permissions to your normal file-creation values, which do not include `executable`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant is this why the system is being corrupted? What if I use the `-a` option for `cp`? Is that how it's done?

Comment: No point preserving permissions unless you know they are right in the Release-Nodejs version. Libraries in /usr/lib seem to use a generic named link to the versioned library. IIRC, you put a new version in place, then switch the link to point to the new version. This ensures processes already running keep the version they started with, new processes get the newer version. I feel writing over a dll that is in use should be avoided.

Comment: Not an "innoffensive script" - this is carrying out open heart surgery on your system without a general anaesthetic. The hard-coded ANSI sequences suggest bad programming practices. Even if you managed to copy the files, this breaks your system in many different ways. If you really MUST use these files (which I sincerely doubt) put them somewhere else and override LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: The question really should be about `Nodejs`.  Why the dependency on this particular set of libraries

Comment: I really hope you're just perpetrating this atrocity on your own systems, and aren't planning on using this as part of a brawndo installer for some totally amazing piece of software you've released on github or somewhere.

Comment: @symcbean I really shall use these libraries. The target doesn't have them and the node module needs them to run. I can't update the target to include these versions so I'm trying to "inject" them. If I knew another way I definitely would do it.

Comment: @cas don't worry this is never going to be public. I don't use github, I have a private git server and this is for private deployment. I'm testing this on a VM for not breaking a real machine. But I need to do this one way or another.

Comment: even on a private VM, what you're trying to do is a bad idea.  You do know that containers and namespaces and chroots exist, right?   Don't break the OS, install weird incompatible stuff into its own container, or at least a chroot.   or just write a wrapper script to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for whatever it is you want to run that doesn't work with the system libraries.   [XY Problems](https://xyproblem.info/) don't usually involve breaking the system, but I guess there's a first time for everything.

Comment: @cas The thing is that I actually asked first about the problem I'm trying to solve and nobody cared. The question was in the open for 2 days and only had 4 views whereas this one got a ton of attention almost immediately. I ended up deleting the question. I will add the original problem here as an edit to the OP and see if that helps. I know what I'm trying to do is a dirty hack, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: "destroying my computer" grabs attention way more than something like "i want to run two versions of nodejs".   Pretty much anything else would be better than what you're doing...starting with examining whatever it is that won't run with the system's version of nodejs to see if it can be modified to work with the system's nodejs, or looking for an alternative that doesn't require its own custom interpreter.   Failing that, install the newer nodejs (and libs) in a separate directory, and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and any nodejs variables in a wrapper script that runs your special-needs program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it again except create the directory "mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs", and set your LIBPATH to "export LIBPATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/". However, I strongly recommend you read how to install nodejs on linux before you pull the trigger. See "https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux", for instance - which does the installation in "/usr/local/lib/nodejs". The only heavy lifting you need to do after you create the directory is download the binary and extract it into the directory "/usr/local/lib/nodejs"

Comment: The target system has a version of nodejs already that I can't modify. That's why I'm attempting this. So it is not a question about how to installed or even update nodejs, it is about how to put these libraries where the node module wants them to avoid updating or otherwise modify the current installation.

Comment: What do you mean modify it?  A kill shot to the operating system is modifying the current installation. To paraphrase, you don't want to modify the current installation, but you want to put the supposely new files where nodejs can find them. How is that not modifying the installed version? I give up.